# decalare method depend on superclass in php

Tags: php, static

I want to declare method in child class as static or non static depend on parent class.
I'm using php and due to change in version I'm getting this issue can anyone please help?
here is example that demonstrate what exactly has changed

```
//in earlier version
class parent{

  function test(){
    //some code here
  }
}

class child extends parent{

  function test(){
    //some code here
  }
}
```

---

```
//in new version
class parent{

  static function test(){
    //some code here
  }
}

class child extends parent{

  function test(){
    //some code here
  }
}
```

**Fatal error: Cannot make static method parent::test() non static in class child**

I want my code to be compatible with both version.what should i do?

Comment: If the class is supposed to be static in the parent and non-static in the child, it is an indicator that the methods are not the same, so you should not overload them in the child but write a new method.

Comment: Well, either make it `static` or not. It can't be both. What do you mean you want to change it "depending on the parent"? Is this going to change dynamically?

Comment: I want to make compatible with both older and newer version :( I can make changes in child class but not in parent

Comment: Why would the class extend both the older and the newer version? The two simply aren't compatible.

Comment: some code has to be executed using parent::find

Comment: Compatible with both version of what?

Comment: You are using a library which defined the parent class. You want to create a subclass which supports both versions of the library?

Comment: Can you please try to answer the questions? Why does it have to be compatible with both? Why can your class possibly have two different incompatible parent classes?

Comment: [Here be Vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires)

Comment: I have some user with older framework and some user with new framework and i have created add-on (I cant disclose the name of framework)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preface: This is a really bad idea. If your base framework had such a fundamental change between two versions that the API has broken backwards compatibility, you should make two separate versions of your class targeting the old and new version separately. It's most likely not simply the function signature that changed to `static`, you'll most likely have to change a lot of code to work with that new `static` way of doing things.

To answer your literal question though: You cannot make *one* class which is compatible with both, since the change is simply incompatible. You can dynamically declare a different class depending on which version you're targeting though. If the base framework doesn't have an obvious version number you can read, you can introspect the parent class:

```
$class  = new ReflectionClass('Parent');
$method = $class->getMethod('test');

if ($method->isStatic()) {
    // include code for new version
    require_once 'child.new.class.php';
} else {
    // include code for old version
    require_once 'child.old.class.php';
}
```

Again, **this is a pretty bad idea** due to the code duplication under the same name. But it's the only choice.

Comment: Great implementation of bad solution! Upvote!

Comment: Hi loler thanks for the reply I will validate it and use this,This is best suitable in my situation:)

Answer (score 0):

You can not override static method with a non static method. You can try simple overriding in child

```
public static function test(){
 //some code here
 }
```

if it's acceptable in your case.

Truly, you are stuck in a very bad way of coding. You have to find better solution than checking if in parent class there is a static or non static method.

Comment: Yes, this will defiantly work but I want it child will work for either case of parent.you are right,but could you suggest me another way?